# How do I distinguish between 2 views with the same name in RegionManager.RequestNavigate call?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, prism

I have 2 views with the same name "RootView" that come from different namespaces: "Foo" and "Bar". What exactly do I have to pass as a view name to RegionManage.RequestNavigate method?

```
this.regionManager.RequestNavigate("MainRegion", "RootView"); // <--- RootView from Foo or Bar?
```

As always there is nothing said about it on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg418956(v=pandp.40).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is: Full name

```
this.regionManager.RequestNavigate("MainRegion", typeof(Foo.RootView).FullName); // <--- RootView from Foo or Bar?
```

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Don't reference the type directly - that direct dependency is one of the things that navigation is trying to avoid.

Comment: @Mark, What should I use then?

Comment: So the idea of navigation is that one view wants to open an entity it knows something about, but doesn't know how the entity should be displayed. If you already know the exact type of the viewer for the entity, you don't need to navigate, you can instantiate the type, and inject the view.

Comment: To use navigation correctly, the URI should be something along the lines of `/MyEntityDisplay?UUID={0000-000-0-0-0-0}`

Then you have an unrelated module that knows something about how to display `MyEntity` objects, which will pick up that navigation request.

With MEF, you can export your class with a contract name (e.g. MyEntityViewer), which isn't the type name of the class, but is a meaningful name to be used for navigation. I assume you can do a similar thing with Unity.

Comment: I have a region and a top level menu that knows about all views. I have a command bound to a menu item that executes that very line of code with RegionNavigate. Do you think I need to inject a view instead?

Comment: Perhaps the question you should ask yourself is, should your top level menu "know" about all views? This, in itself, is counter to the principles of composite application development. In your case, it may still be worthwhile to still use navigation instead of view injection, as you also benefit from the `INavigationAware` interaction.